# Distribution of ratio of 2 points drawn from normal distribution?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, expectation, standard-deviation

Let's say we have a known normal distribution $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$.

I now draw 2 points $p1$ and $p2$ randomly from this Gaussian distribution for every observation, and repeat this process large number of times.

(1) What will the distribution of $p1 / p2$ look like? Will it be normal? Can we say something about it's mean and standard deviation?

(2) What will the distribution of $max(p1 / p2, p2/p1)$ look like? Will it be normal? Can we say something about it's mean and standard deviation?

(3) What will the distribution of $e^p_1 / e^p_2$ and the distribution of $max(e^p_1 / e^p_2, e^p_2/ e^p_1)$ look like? Will it be normal? Can we say something about it's mean and standard deviation?

Comment: A lot of calculations! The ratio has distribution a version of the Cauchy. The mean does not exist.